# Is there a way to ignore "\n" while writing to a text file in R?

Tags: r, delimiter

Am trying to write a summary onto excel using text file. Here is the example of how it looks like in R output.

*[1] "\n\nDuring the post-intervention period, the response variable had an average value of approx.196.08K. In the absence of an intervention, we would have expected an average response of 199.41K.*

However, when i write this to a text file using write.table this is how the text file looks like

*During the post-intervention period, the response variable had an average value of approx.196.08K.

In the absence of an intervention, we would have expected an average response of 199.41K.*

Here is the code am using for this.

```
write.table(analysis_text, file = "analysis_text.txt", sep = "",
            row.names = TRUE, col.names = NA)
```

Is there anyway i can ignore "/n" while writing into txt file in R?

Comment: If you want to ignore "\n", maybe you can do some pre-processing on your `analisys_text`, i.e., gsub("\n","",analisys_text), which removes "\n" in your texts...

Comment: Yields the same result, good suggestion though! Maybe i should give more details in the question

Comment: Yes, more information is needed to show what you are exactly looking for...

Comment: This worked Thomas! Thank you so much! I had forgot to assign it back to the same variable.

Comment: I added my complete answer so you can try it directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore "\n", maybe you can do some pre-processing on your `analisys_text`, i.e., `gsub("\n","",analisys_text)`, which removes "\n" in your texts.

In this sense, you code should be like

```
write.table(gsub("\n","",analisys_text), 
            file = "analysis_text.txt", 
            sep = "",
            row.names = TRUE, 
            col.names = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `write.table` help, the function can also take an `eol` argument, which defaults to `\n`.

Change that to `eol=""` and you should be fine.

Comment: thank you so much for your swift response @Tasos, it still looks the same however(with eol="")

Comment: ah, apologies, I must have misunderstood the question then. Your output seems weird though ... is that line really a single row with no `\n` characters at the offending part?

Comment: Yes, and more. While it was a single paragraph in R. it got separated into 2 lines while writing into text file. Makes sense?

Comment: why are you using `write.table` anyway? "analysis_text" looks like a simple string? why not just `write` or `cat`?

Comment: I tried to use cat, yields the same result. cat(analysis_text, sep = "", file = "analysis_text.txt", append = TRUE)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in either case. The fault must lie somewhere else. If I do `analysis_text = "bla bla bla"` (with your content copied from above) and then either of the two commands as you tried them, I get that line uninterrupted as I would expect.